# Fixed columns' width in Nautilus

Tags: 11.10, nautilus, configuration

In Ubuntu 11.10 the nautilus version has a new feature, as you can see: it adapts the column's width to the content of the column itself (at least for the Name column).

This behavior is not always desirable, so I am looking for a way to disable it.

Comment: I have tried to do this with nautilus, but have only succeeded with thunar -in that file manager you can manually define your column widths in list view, then go to view > configure columns > and uncheck 'automatically expand columns as needed'.

Comment: I'd be interested in an answer for this as well. Please mind my bounty of 50 reputation!

Comment: +1 if this could be solved for 12.04 as well! Someone inclined to open a bug/feature-request for the Nautilus devs?

Answer (score 6):

### Before Ubuntu 12.10

As this seems to be hard-coded into Nautilus, your best bet be to report a bug, as there is no solution short of patching Nautilus. Even with the newer versions of Nautilus that use dconf, there is no option to change this setting:

[image: Proof]

### Ubuntu 12.10 and up

In Ubuntu 12.10 (so far) it seems Nautilus no longer has this problem. If the final version comes with the standard Nautilus 3.6, you will be able to change the column width freely.

Answer (score 3):

As *Roland Taylor* said, the way `Nautilus` handles columns is at present not easily tweakable without writing some additional code and patching the application, which would not be trivial to do because of the way column handling is built in to `Nautilus`. There really is no way to do it in `Nautilus` by altering any configuration settings.

However, I was encouraged by ***con-f-use*** to give an answer relating to `Thunar`, the lightweight [Xfce file manager](http://thunar.xfce.org/). In `Thunar` it is very easy to set the widths of the columns in list view and they stay *fixed* until you feel the need to alter them. All you need to do is go to view > configure columns and **uncheck** the setting to 'automatically expand columns as needed'.

The screenshot displays the column setting and behind it you can see the adjusted columns in list view- any changes made to them are saved when exiting `Thunar`, unlike in `Nautilus`.

Future versions of `Nautilus` will probably adopt this feature (*Ronald Taylor* points out that it may be available in `Nautilus` 3.6 in Ubuntu 12.10), but for now this `Thunar` solution is unfortunately the only solution for people who want fixed columns.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem under Ubuntu 14.04, Nautilus 3.10.1.

In Nautilus edit/file settings/display I checked "navigate folders in tree view" and discovered that the problems are gone.

I use German system language, therefore the exact names might be off.

Answer (score -1):

As i only have installed the German version, some translations of the menu might be different, but anyhow it will work if you enter the values below.

Configure fixed column-width

1. open Terminal
2. type in `gconf-editor /apps/nautilus/list_view`
3. [right mouseclick] -> create / make  key
4. at name type in: `all_columns_have_same_width`

   type:        boolean

   value:       true
5. close the editor. et voilà

Or, simply, execute `gconftool-2 --type boolean --set /apps/nautilus/list_view/all_columns_have_same_width true` in Terminal

The column width will stay now the same in nautilus, no matter of the length of the file name.
Also after closing and re-opening, all columns will have the same size.

Good alternatives to the nautilus commander are: "Krusader", "Tux-Commander" and for whom who is missing Norton Commander : "GNOME Commander".

(For a continuesly backup i would entrust you „back in time“)

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. From a googling, it seems an option associate to compact_view.

Comment: based on this: http://people.gnome.org/~bmsmith/gconf-docs/C/nautilus.html all_columns_have_same_width isn't in the nautilus schema.

Comment: Confirmed for 12.04: *doesn't work*, even crashed my Nautilus. So I removed the key again...

Comment: Didn't work for me.