# How can I adjust the column width and make it default? With dconf-editor (nautilus) I can adjust which columns, but the width?

Tags: nautilus, filemanager, dconf, gconf

After one day of searching how I can adjust my default column width? See the below details and what I already tried during my troubleshooting.

- gnome/nautilus installed
- via dconf-editor I can adjust my file-manager-nautilus layout, via list-view I can adjust which columns. So far so good, but I have one more request.
- for the perfect list-view layout I want to adjust the column width as well but unfortunately I can't find this option.
- Installed dolphin, but I still can't adjust the column width.
- Installed gconftool2 and tried "conftool-2 --type boolean --set /apps/nautilus/list_view/all_columns_have_same_width true" --> no error, but I don't see result in layout.
- to look if something works related to layout I tried `gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.window-state sidebar-width 111` --> Yes, this works. It's not what I want, but at least I can see something.
- I asked for support from two experienced Linux/Ubuntu user colleagues, but unfortunately they didn't know
- I don't know any more things I can try.

Columns custom view works:

[image: columns custom view works]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fixed columns' width in Nautilus](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70979/fixed-columns-width-in-nautilus)

Comment: Nautilus does not have this feature. Dolphin and Thunar are separate file managers that ***replace*** Nautilus like how Chrome and Firefox replace each other. You need to click their separate icon from the applications menu. With Thunar, the other answer tells you how to make fixed the column width. With Dolphin, this is by default.